# VisualStudio curly brackets won't indent macos

Tags: c#, macos, visual-studio

I downloaded and installed visual studio on my mac to work with xamarin and every time I try to use the text editor I just can't.
This is how the layout looks like:

[Visual studio text editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QfhkM.png)

And this is how it looks like when I use monoDevelop instead:

[MonoDevelop text editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/erIrQ.png)

Now, I want to use xamarin and I can't seem to find a solution to the brackets acting they way they do. If anyone can help I would much appriciate it. It's been bothering me for a while now.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the tabs for C# were not set up correctly within your Visual Studio.

Please try the following:

a) On the 'Tools' menu, click 'Options'.
b) Click 'Text Editor'.
c) Open C# and click 'Tabs'.
d) Make sure that 'Smart' Indentation is selected.

For further information please check out: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/999b219z(v=vs.71).aspx

**Note**
 
You can automatically let Visual Studio indent your code:

- Autoformat selection: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Autoformat document: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

Comment: I can't find 'Options' under the Tools menu. and i've already set the indentation to smart through the preferences. take a look:
https://imgur.com/5rEAGNT
It might be important to note that my computer is set to a different language using Left to Right (Hebrew)