# Curly brackets indention in Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: c#, visual-studio-mac, curly-braces

I use Visual Studio for Mac and the curly brackets in my code are not indented automatically and they are aligned to the left.

Have somebody encountered this issue? How can I fix it?

[image: here].

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46380450/visualstudio-curly-brackets-wont-indent-macos help?

Comment: Nope, it didn't work. Any other solution?

Comment: It do that, right out of the box?  Odd ...

Answer (score 16):

1. Open the `Preferences`
2. Select `Source Code`
3. Under the `Source Code`; Select `Code Formatting`
4. Select `C# Source Code`
5. New page popped-up
6. Select `C# Format` tab in the new page then press the `Edit` button
7. Change `Indention` to `New Lines` in the `Category` section

Now, you can set your custom format settings as you want...

[image: First Page]
[image: Popup Page]

Answer (score 3):

To Format Existing Code in Visual Studio for Mac

Highlight the code and in the edit menu select Format --> Format Selection.

To Adjust the Auto Formatting Settings in Visual Studio for Mac

In the Visual Studio Menu Select Preferences --> Source Code. --> Code Formatting -->  C# Formatting.   There is an option to select a few Policy one of them is Visual Studio

[image: Visual Studio for Mac C# format settings]

Comment: It also doesn't help. :(

Answer (score -2):

To resolved this, I went to:
Preferences-> Source Code-> Code Formatting-> C# Source Code

Under Policy, Select "Microsoft Visual Studio"
Click Ok
Restart Visual Studio.

Then you should be set!